# How do I reassign a variable name in R?

Tags: r, variables

I am loading from .rda files and the variable in the rda files are called "result"

I want to change the name of result after I load in a function call. I am unsure how to rename a variable in a function.

Say I want to change the name to

```
new_name_result <- result
```

I can do this explicitly, but I am loading from multiple .rda files and want to do something pro-grammatically.

```
paste0(new_name ,"_result") <- result
```

Something similar to this so the name can change with the name of the different .rda file.

Comment: You can use `assign`, see `?assign` for details. A good way might be to `load` the rda files each into their own environments and use the `assign` within that environment. Then your function could return the environment or attach it to the parent or global environment. (But attaching to the global environment is risky - you may want your function to be usable by another function).

Comment: You should post code to create a character vector of file names and show how you had planned to do this. You will probably need to make a copy with the new name, and remove the old copy. How this would be done will depend on hte specifics of the naming convention you have chosen. The term "variable" is not actually helpful in understanding what you are working with. R objects are possibly lists, atomic vectors of variaous sorts or S4 objects. None of them are properly referred to as "variables".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
assign(paste0("new_name", "_result"), result)
```

Comment: assign(paste0(new_name, "_result"), result) This worked. In addition if you want to pro-grammatically  return this in a function you can use the 
     get(paste0(new_name,"_result")